# Xamarin SkiaSharp Scaling a crop canvas

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

I try to get a polygonal cropping from a photo i capture from my app in Xamarin Foms.
I use SkiaSharp .So the first step is ok i get a canvas from my EdgeCroppingView like this

[image]

So now I want crop the selection and "resize" in full screen only the selection (around the cat) and i have this :

[image]

```
The selected skpath (the borders) are correctly "resizing" but not the inside content(the cat's area) : i would like to strech this area ...
```

Any idea ?

```
 private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
        
        canvas.Clear();

        if (_pathToClip != null)
        {
             SKRect rectSource;
            _pathToClip.GetTightBounds(out rectSource);

            e.Surface.Canvas.Clear();
            SKRect canvasRect = SKRect.Create(e.Info.Size);

            //I need to find the size of the path
            SKRect pathRect = _pathToClip.TightBounds;

            //I want to find the largest rectangle that can fit on my canvas maintaining the path's aspect ratio
            //SkiaSharp added a builtin method for this based on code from me

            SKRect drawPathRect = canvasRect.AspectFit(pathRect.Size);
            //Now I need to transform the path to draw within the drawPathRect
            //First translate original path to its own origin
            SKMatrix firstTranslateM = SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(-pathRect.Left, -pathRect.Top);
            //Next handle scaling.  Since I maintained aspect ratio, I should be able to use either
            //width or height to figure out scaling factor
            float scalingFactor = drawPathRect.Width / pathRect.Width;
            SKMatrix scaleM = SKMatrix.CreateScale(scalingFactor, scalingFactor);
            //Last I need to handle translation so path is centered on canvas
            SKMatrix secondTranslateM = SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(drawPathRect.Left, drawPathRect.Top);
            //Now combine the translation, scaling, and translation into a single matrix by matrix multiplication/concatentation
            SKMatrix transformM = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
            SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref transformM, firstTranslateM);
            SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref transformM, scaleM);
            SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref transformM, secondTranslateM);
            
            //Now apply the transform to the path
            _pathToClip.Transform(transformM);
            

            canvas.ClipPath(_pathToClip);

           using (var paint = new SKPaint())
            {
                paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
                paint.Color = SKColors.Magenta;
                paint.StrokeWidth = 5;

                canvas.DrawPath(_pathToClip, paint);
                canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, info.Rect, BitmapStretch.UniformToFill );
            }

          
        }
```

Comment: I try to check your code with SkisSharp. But i got some complier erros with `SKMatrix.CreateIdentity`, `SKMatrix.CreateScale`, `SKMatrix.CreateTranslation`. Am i missing something for this? Do you use the Xamarin Skiasharp?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Yes , i'm using SkiaSharp latest version. You need to set _pathToClip (the SKRect's cropped region) .before invalidate Canvas